# Perl script fails when selecting data from big PostgreSQL table

Tags: perl, postgresql, memory, fetch

I'm trying to run a SELECT statement on PostgreSQL database and save its result into a file.

The code runs on my environment but fails once I run it on a lightweight server.

I monitored it and saw that the reason it fails after several seconds is due to a lack of memory (the machine has only 512MB RAM). I didn't expect this to be a problem, as all I want to do is to save the whole result set as a JSON file on disk.

I was planning to use `fetchrow_array` or `fetchrow_arrayref` functions hoping to fetch and process only one row at a time.

Unfortunately I discovered there's no difference when it comes to the true fetch operations between the two above and `fetchall_arrayref` when you use `DBD::Pg`. My script fails at the `$sth->execute()` call, even before it has a chance to do call any `fetch...` function.

This suggests to me that the implementation of `execute` in `DBD::Pg` actually fetches ALL the rows into memory, leaving only the actual format its returned to the `fetch...` functions.

A quick look at the [DBI documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RowsInCache) gives a hint:

> If the driver supports a local row cache for SELECT statements, then this attribute holds the number of un-fetched rows in the cache. If the driver doesn't, then it returns undef. Note that some drivers pre-fetch rows on execute, whereas others wait till the first fetch.

So in theory I would just need to set the [`RowCacheSize` parameter](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#RowCacheSize). I've tried but this feature [doesn't seem to be implemented by `DBD::Pg`](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/TURNSTEP/DBD-Pg-3.0.0/Pg.pm#RowCacheSize)

> Not used by DBD::Pg

I find this limitation a huge general problem (`execute()` call pre-fetches *all* rows?) and more inclined to believe that I'm missing something here, than that this is actually a true limitation of interacting with PostgreSQL databases using Perl.

---

Update (2014-03-09): My script works now thanks to using a workaround as described in my comment to Borodin's answer. The maintainer of `DBD::Pg` library got back to me on the issue actually saying the root cause is deeper and lies within `libpq` postgresql internal library  (used by `DBD::Pg`). Also, I think very similar issue to the one described here affects pgAdmin. Being postgresql native tool it still doesn't give in the `Options` chance to define the default limit of the result set row size. This is probably why it makes `Query tool` sometimes waiting a good while before presenting results from bulky queries, potentially breaking the app in some cases too.

Comment: Wouldn't be out of place to contact the maintainers for this. See bottom of DBD::Pg ("The current maintainers may be reached ...")

Comment: I did that of course. Just been determined to meet my requirements regardless of getting it supported or finding a plausible workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [section *Cursors*](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3aPg#Cursors), the documentation for the database driver says this

> Therefore the "execute" method fetches all data at once into data structures located in the front-end application. This fact must to be considered when selecting large amounts of data!

So your supposition is correct. However the same section goes on to describe how you *can* use cursors in your Perl application to read the data in chunks. I believe this would fix your problem.

Another alternative is to use `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` clauses on your `SELECT` statement to emulate cursor functionality. If you write

```
my $select = $dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM table OFFSET ? LIMIT 1');
```

then you can say something like (all of this is untested)

```
my $i = 0;
while ($select->execute($i++)) {
  my @data = $select->fetchrow_array;
  # Process data
}
```

to read your tables one row at a time.

You may find that you need to increase the chunk size to get an acceptable level of efficiency.

Comment: The way with cursors should be more efficient, although also a little trickier because it's stateful.

Comment: Thought about that (`OFFSET` & `LIMIT`) but that would rather be not efficient as requires sending multiple queries. Also the each query would need to have `ORDER BY` column to ensure consistency in the consolidated output.  
The [DBD Cursors](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD%3a%3aPg#Cursors) workaround you pointed out works for me. I've made small improvement taking redundant `prepare(…)` out of the loop:                                   
    $dbh->do("DECLARE csr CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR $sql");
    my $sth = $dbh->prepare("fetch $fetchSize from mytable");
    while (1) {…